# UPI payment href link causes error when confirming tx

Tags: android, web, payment, google-pay, upi

**Some background:**

In a web app that I developed a while back in around June/July 2020, I implemented an HTML button that when clicked would direct the user (on a smartphone) to a UPI app for making a payment with the recipient and amount pre populated. It used to work as intended but recently it's started being problematic.

**The problem:**

The button link is such:

```
<a href="upi://pay?pa=abc_user@xyz_bank&amp;mc=1234&amp;pn=abc_user%40xyz_bank&amp;tid=czzzxnkjcnkjdfdvjndkjfvn&amp;tr=4zzz894398cndhcd23&amp;tn=aaa&amp;am=500&amp;mam=null&amp;cu=INR" class="btn btn-primary">Go</a>
```

Now, when this button is clicked, it sends the user to the UPI app, to Google Pay for example; but when the transaction is confirmed, it shows an error as such:

```
Payment failed
You've exceeded the transaction amount set by your bank.
```

This error only shows when the payment is made by following the link in the web app. When the same transaction is attempted manually, i.e., by going into the UPI app and filling in the details before confirming, it works fine.

I would like to know what the reason for this behaviour is, especially because it used to work just fine a while ago.

**Additional info:**

I've read in certain posts that some UPI apps, including Google Pay, have started rejecting payments initiated from outside but I haven't been able to find any official information on this.

Comment: If you are sending payment of 1 rupees, change this to more than 10 rupees. Try with 20. Also make sure your internet is not dropping the connection during the payment process.

Comment: @Muzammil I have tried with Rs 500 and the connection isn't dropping.

Comment: Does the following answer apply to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64481458/getting-error-you-have-exceeded-the-maximum-transaction-amount-set-by-your-bank/64724053#64724053

Comment: @Soc it doesn't apply directly but I have already had a look at it and incorporated the parameters in my solution and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Hii @mrZ I have implemented the upi in web like this. Try using a business account/upi id (PhonePe id recommended). And How are you managing the response when payment is failed or success. I am not getting any response in web even if when payment is success/failure. If you know how to get the response from this upi:// url after the payment. Please show me how you did it. Thanks!. and waiting...

Comment: try phonepe business, i have tested it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using merchant VPA to complete transaction. You can also callback when you raise transaction using upi:// deep link all just you have to do hit an intent and write catch it's response in result launcher or onActivityResult

```
val upiIntent= Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link))
upiPaymentResult.launch(browserIntent)
```

callback:

```
 private var upiPaymentResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val data: Intent? = result.data
        if (data != null) {
            val extra = data.extras
            if(extra!=null){
                val keySet = extra.keySet()
                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                keySet.forEach {
                    jsonObject.put(it, extra.get(it).toString())
                }
                Log.d("UPI RESPONSE", jsonObject.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Phonepe response:

```
{"Status":"Failed","isExternalMerchant":"true","txnRef":"","response":"txnId=YBL8bc3&txnRef=644&Status=Failed&responseCode=01","bleTxId":"T2309064","txnId":"YB163914093a93649a9","responseCode":"01"}
```